# RedHat 5 - pstack and gdb

Tags: linux

I'm chasing a weird bug and I have a clue, but I don't know what it means.

I have a program that uses OpenGL and Motif running on RH5 workstations. On two machines, the program takes 5 minutes or so to come up, when on all the other machines (five of them), it comes up immediately. All seven machines are loaded the same and have the same hardware.

So here's my clue. If I run the process on either of the two "slow" machines under gdb, or do a pstack while it is hung, it comes up right away. I know this must be telling me something important, but I cannot figure out what.

Any ideas?

Edit - To be more clear - Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5

Comment: A random guess would be that `pstack` and `gdb` cause a signal (due to attaching via `ptrace`), interrupting some sort of wait in the kernel.

Comment: Try issuing a SIGABRT while the process is hung to see if you can catch where the program is hung when it dumps core.

Answer (score 0):

A clear example of:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug

Red Hat Linux 5 is ancient. I don't think you can expect any good help for it.

If you happened to write RH5 by mistake but it really is RHEL (Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5) then contact Red Hat support. They can help you debug your issue.

As for debugging I'm not sure what do you have with so old distro. but you can try changing some components the program is using to help you understand where issue comes from. For example X server (perhaps try vnc). Or try swapping HDD of machines to see if it is some hardware problem or a BIOS difference.